# How to insert values then delete after merge when matched in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to delete values when id is matched in merged table (example: same id is in 3 rows)

after deleted matched rows then i want to insert new values instead of deleted rows.


I need to delete resID matched rows then insert new rows
(if user uses browser's back button and then presses again to the next(page) button rows should be delete then have to be inserted new rows) [image]

Comment: Can you give some sample data to show exactly what you need? Right now it looks like you really want to update if the id is matched.

Comment: I have loaded an image. Hope it s clear.